Show featured image when hovering menu link - Wordpress
In Wordpress, I'd like to display the post featured image when hovering on its menu link.
It must be user friendly for my client. On each project he will just have to set the featured image and add the page to the menu.
It seems like I need to use the args from wp_nav_menu items.
And I found an anwser that's 7 years old : Add featured image to wp_nav_menu items
It works to a point because it gets rid of the text link.
What do you guys think?
In condition it will look something like this : 
